# Printer buffer overflow over serial port

Tags: serial-port, buffer-overflow

I have a printer (specifically, a Braillo 200 embosser) that is connected via a serial port to a computer running Windows 7. I installed a "generic text" printer in Windows and set it to use the serial port. The parameters on the serial port dialog (printer properties -> ports -> configure port) match those on the embosser. Despite this, the embosser reports a buffer overflow when trying to emboss files larger than 2K.

My research on this issue indicates a handshaking problem but I tried all handshaking options (hardware, software, none) and none have solved the problem.

I did notice that by using the mode.exe command and setting the parameters there, it is possible to print form the command line (using copy.exe *file_name* com1). But, I would rather use Windows to manage printers.

Any suggestions will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: You _might_ have better luck with this on http://www.superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to set the write timeouts using the Win32 function SetCommTimeouts.  I don't know if it will work but it's the only thing I can think of.